# Accessing Verilog genvar generated instances in simulation code

Tags: simulation, verilog, hdl, synthesis

This is a Verilog releated question. I am working with XILINX ISE as a dev environment.

I am trying to access variables in the simulation that are automatically generated using genvar but I am receiving the following error -> HDLCompiler:71

Problem Example:

```
genvar i;

generate

for(i=0; i < N; i=i+1)

begin:Sys_Modules

  TypeXModule #(.width(10)) xmod(.dataY(dataY)));

end

endgenerate
```

When I ran synthesis or simulation I can see that Sys_Modules[0..N-1].xmod instances are created.

When I try to add a line to the simulation accessing the Sys_Modules array:

Sys_Modules[i].xmod.dataY

I get the following error:

HDLCompiler:71 dataY is not declared under prefix xmod

Is there any way to access automatically generated values in the simulation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is legal to write a hierarchical reference to a generated instance. The functionality is described in sections 2.7.2 and 12.1.3 of the IEEE Verilog standard. However, the instance subscript must be a constant so that it can be resolved at compile time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I have managed to compile a version using a constant.
Unfortunately I have a module that is dynamically generated using genvar and a parameter. The for loop is going from I to N and N is defined as a parameter(parameter=N).
Using a constant kind of defeats the purpose of using a genvar for loop.  A Compiler can easily determine the constant value from the parameter.  If it’s true it seems like an oversight in the Verilog language design.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use cross-instance hierarchical references in synthesized Verilog.

Comment: Thanks. Why is that cross ref? The same problem happens when used inside the module with genvar.

Comment: The reference xmod.dataY accesses the signal dataY inside the instance of TypeXModule from the parent module.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're out of luck. Simulators don't seem to like out-of-module references (OOMRs) pointing into generated blocks as you've discovered.

I encountered a similar problem recently when making a parameterizable testbench monitor. I'd a variable number of sub-blocks instantiated depending on a `parameter`. Within this, I needed to have a toplevel `.start()` task that called the `.start()` tasks in each of the instantiated modules. I couldn't use a `for` loop to do this because of this OOMR problem.

So I ended up having to:

- define a `reg` that the toplevel `.start()` task toggled
- write an `always @` block triggered on this `reg`
- write *another* `generate` section within this always block to call `.start()` on each of the sub-modules.

If you really need to peek into your `generate`d modules, maybe you could try a workaround like above? For instance, have a bus at the toplevel, and use a`generate` statement to peek inside your original `generate`d instantiations to copy/assign interesting signals on to this toplevel bus.

Answer (score 0):

I have found and used another solution, posting it here in case someone will find it useful. Worked for me in Vivado 2020.

Steps:

1. in tb: declare all data you need to print (declare wires)

   ex:for Sys_Modules[0..N-1], wanting Sys_Modules[i].xmod.dataY =>

   tb: wire [0:N-1][`DATA_SIZE-1:0] tb_Sys_Modules_dataY;
2. generate all connections using a generate block

   ex:  (N should be a define/parameter)

   for(i = 0 ; i < N ;i = i + 1)
   assign tb_Sys_Modules_dataY[i] = Sys_Modules[i].xmod.dataY;
3. $display wire from tb:

   ex:

   $display("%d",tb_Sys_Modules_dataY[i]);